# Got blank page when add custom javascript to my CustomMasterPage

Tags: javascript, custom-masterpage

I'm follwing this tutorial to branding master page and totally successful. 
http://sharepoint.rackspace.com/sharepoint-2013-how-to-change-sharepoint-branding-text-in-the-upper-left-part-of-your-screen
But when Im trying to do the same step with custom.js . I've got a blank page. Can you guys help me :).
Here's my link to add script :

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="custom.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
```

I've added it right under

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration1" name="&lt;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/style library/custom.css %&gt;" runat="server" after="style.css" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SharePoint:ScriptLink` requires you to use SP.SOP.execute in order to load the script. Like this ([reference](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94422/reference-jscript-files-at-the-end-of-page-using-scriptlink-tag)):

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myfunction, 'sp.js');
function myfunction() {
  // my custom code
  //
  SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myfunction2, 'custom.js'); //change
}

SP.SOD.notifyScriptLoadedAndExecuteWaitingJobs("sp.js");
```

Try using the `<script>` tag instead to have it always load.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~site/style library/js/custom.js" runat="server" />
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.scriptlink.ASPX

Comment: After add <script type="text/javascript" src="~site/style library/js/custom.js" runat="server" /> I got Error "Sorry, somethings went wrong". Even I've try to changed ~sitecol ~sitecollection instead ~site . Because I'm working in sitecollection

Comment: ahhh, I've fixed . there's no runat="server" in script tag. My site loaded, but went i'm press F12 . in Console I've seen 3 errors . Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onsubmit' of null ScriptResource.axd?
Uncaught ReferenceError: theForm is not defined (index):784
Uncaught ReferenceError: theForm is not defined

Comment: did you have the function above in your code?

Comment: in .master I've added : "<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Style Library/Js/custom.js"/>" . In my custom.js "SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myfunction, 'sp.js');
function myfunction() {
 var x= "hello";
 alert(x);  
  SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myfunction2, 'custom.js');
}

SP.SOD.notifyScriptLoadedAndExecuteWaitingJobs("sp.js");"

Comment: THen I have one more error "Uncaught ReferenceError: myfunction2 is not defined "

Comment: you are referencing a function called function2 in your code that isn't defined, search for function2..

Comment: what do you mean "search for function2" ???? This from your code you gave me. :) . I don't know what function2 is?

Comment: You need to change the `function2` with a function you want to load from your custom javascript. Look at the code again in my answer

Answer (score 1):

What is it you're trying to achieve here and why does that tutorial make it so unnecessarily complicated??

If you simply want to add some custom JavaScript or jQuery-enable your site, then simply reference them in the masterpage using  tags as already stated.

Then in your custom.js add any functions you want to occur after page load into $(document).ready() function. And define any on demand functions and references outside this.

I stronlgy advise leaving any SOD methods well out of a global js file until you have managed to master a simple alert.

Clear the contents of your custom.js and add the following as a test:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    alert('My custom.js loaded);
});
```

Once you have that working....slowly add additional functionality.

Comment: it alert 'My custom.js loaded' . but it effect to sharepoint site, when i'm F12 in browser and I saw 3 errors in console window.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onsubmit' of null ScriptResource.axd? ------
Uncaught ReferenceError: theForm is not defined (index):784 -----
Uncaught ReferenceError: theForm is not defined

Comment: @user3622351 these are unrelated to your custom javascript file and are coming from other scripts. There can often be dozens loaded for each SharePoint page. Why are you focusing on warnings and errors from sources you can't control?

Answer (score 1):

For a Custom User Action (CUA) you need to reference using a token, I was messing around with using an anonymous public CDN to host my scriptsrc.  Couple of odd behaviors, when referenced with a full path it failed with 2 exceptions, most notably when i added a folder path  /_layouts/15/xxx..js the CUA started working.

Post about it here: http://blog.sharepointsite.co.uk/2017/11/using-cdn-for-custom-user-actions.html